# PayPal integration - issue in redirecting

Tags: model-view-controller, payflowlink

I am trying to integrate PayPal in my application (MVC4 C#)

Any link/ guidance in integrating it (step by step explanation) will be really helpful.

Issue is 
Even though my action link is "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"

it redirects to 
"www.sandbox.paypal/home"

Comment: This **is not** a tutorial site.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't append this `?cmd=_express-checkout&token=` with the token then you will be redirected to the home page and not the PayPal Checkout page. The token is gotten from a successful setExpressCheckout request.

The payflow for ExpressCheckout is:

1. SetExpressCheckout request
2. Redirect to PayPal for user authorisation
3. Return to your site
4. GetExpressCheckoutDetails request
5. doExpressCheckoutPayment request

Here's a little diagram of the payflow for it:

[image]